# What to do with answer that has several dead links?

Tags: discussion

The accepted answer for [Mobile phone detection (brand, model, browser etc)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/mobile-phone-detection-brand-model-browser-etc) from 2010 has links that someone has edited to mark as "dead link".

There are enough dead links that to remove them involves almost re-writing the answer to keep it useful.

Is there a protocol for this sort of situation?

Comment: It wasn't just "somebody" that edited the answer.  The person who originally posted the answer came back 10 years later to edit it.  It appears they edited a few times over the years as links died.

Comment: Can mods 301 internal links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe one of the reasons that particular post is so out-of-date is because it's for the most part a recommendation for a 3rd-party tool, in response to a question soliciting recommendations for 3rd-party tools. Those 3rd-party tools posts get dated rather quickly, which is one of a few reasons why they have been off-topic on Webmasters SE for a while now. I just gave it a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for).

For this particular post, there's no good new resource to update the link to, because it's a download link to a specific piece of software that's no longer available from the publisher. I don't believe link rot is nearly as much of a problem for on-topic questions, because there are often alternative resources you can link (e.g. swapping in an MDN page for a dead article about an HTML element).

That said, before I locked the question I updated one of the links to an archive.org snapshot. In situations like this where the post is linking to a very specialized resource (a specific forum post from 2008), I think it can make sense to use an archive.org snapshot when available.

Comment: When I lock such a question I usually comment as to exactly why it would now be considered off-topic.